# Code is not invoking the sign up button and not able to get post sign up URL using selelnium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test the signup page wherein I have written a code that will give all the required details that are required for the website but after filling up all the required fields then it should click on the `Sign Up` button which will redirect to the next URL. Once, it's redirected to the next URL then the validation is passed else fail. To test the URL I am storing into a variable `u` but when I executed the code in the `u` I am getting the original URL only and not redirecting to the post URL.

Code:

```
package Seleniumtesting;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Selenium {
    ChromeDriver driver;
    String url ="https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/";
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        try {
            
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(url);
        String urlFromWebpage = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if(urlFromWebpage.equals("https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/")) {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }
        else {
            
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        
    }
    public void signup(){
        try {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement createAccountHeading = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Create an account or ']"));
        if(createAccountHeading.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("PASS");
        }else
            System.out.println("FAIL");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("Testvidewedrq12435@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testvidwqrdee1243");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Test123");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.findElement(By.name("marketing_newsletter")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='create-account']")).click();
        
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[text()='Check your email']"));
       // System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        String u = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("URL: "+u);
        
        if(u.contains("success"))
        {
            System.out.println("PASS !!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("FAIL !!");
        }
        driver.close();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Selenium mc = new Selenium();
        mc.invokeBrowser();
        mc.signup();
        
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally before validating the *CurrentUrl* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for *`visibilityOfElementLocated()`* for any of the ***visible*** element within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). As an example, waiting for the `h1` with text as ***Welcome to Mailchimp*** to be visible as follows:

```
driver.get(url);
String urlFromWebpage = driver.getCurrentUrl();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'Welcome to Mailchimp')]")));
if(urlFromWebpage.equals("https://login.mailchimp.com/signup/")) {
    System.out.println("PASS");
}
else {
    
    System.out.println("FAIL");
```